# How to have different seeds for random generation in Simulink?

Tags: random, simulink

I have a model in Simulink that uses the `Random Number` block. This `Random Number` block uses a `Seed` value for the generation of random values. Now if I have multiple copies of my model:

```
main.slx
    |
    |-----> child_1.slx (Random Number block inside)
    |
    |
    |-----> child_2.slx (Random Number block inside)
    |
    |
    |-----> child_3.slx (Random Number block inside)
```

How can I set the `Seed` of `Random Number` to be different in each copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to appropriately parameterize your child model.  You do this by using the `Arguments` tab of the [Model](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/model.html) Block (see about 60% of the way down the linked page).

There is also extensive documentation on this, including a worked example.  See [Parameterize Instances of a Reusable Referenced Model](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/parameterize-referenced-models.html) or execute `docsearch('Parameterize Instances of a Reusable Referenced Model')` at the MATLAB command line and choose the first result.